# AbstractMethodError when using isvalid() function with mysql connection object

Tags: java, mysql-connector, sqlconnection, abstract-methods

I am trying overcome mysql connection object timeout problem. I use singleton pattern to get the connection object. My intention is to reinitialize the connection object when mysql connection object timeouts on the server side. Below is my code  :

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
//            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            if(con==null || !con.isValid(0)){
                logger.info("Creating new connection object...");
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + "/" + dbName, userName, pass);
                if(con!=null) logger.info("Connection object creation successful!!");
            }else{
                logger.info("Returning existing connection object...");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Below is the error message I get when attempting to use `isValid` method  :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z
    at com.abc.xml2pdf.db.DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:66)
    at com.abc.xml2pdf.dao.RequestTracking.persistRequest(RequestTracking.java:137)
    at com.abc.xml2pdf.dao.RequestTracking.trackRequest(RequestTracking.java:78)
    at com.abc.xml2pdf.controller.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:61)
    at com.abc.xml2pdf.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:79)
```

When I dig into the problem , I found that `isValid()` method is not implemented in `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`. Am I missing something. Or will I not be able to use `isValid` with mysql connector. I am using the latest mysql [connector 5.0.8](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html). Kindly clarify. Thanks.

Comment: 5.0.8 is not the latest mysql connector.

Comment: Kindly tell me wt's the latest one then.

Comment: Check on the MySQL website or [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.27)

Answer (score 3):

The updated Jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.27) helped me to solve that without any prob. Thanks all!! :)